# Oracle table error: table creating with constraints

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
create table prmr(
    emp_id number(10) primary key,
    name varchar2(10),
    mob number(10) unique key,
    id varchar2(10),
    email varchar2(20)
);
```

When I create this table, it gives me the error `"Missing Parenthesis"`. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Remove `key` from `unique key`

```
CREATE TABLE prmr(
   emp_id number(10) PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar2(10),
   mob number(10) UNIQUE,
   id varchar2(10),
   email varchar2(20)
);
```

There is also a way to specify constraints separately:

```
CREATE TABLE prmr(
   emp_id number(10) NOT NULL,
   name varchar2(10),
   mob number(10),
   id varchar2(10),
   email varchar2(20),
   CONSTRAINT mob_unique UNIQUE (mob),
   CONSTRAINT emp_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)
);
```

I also added `NOT NULL` to the `emp_id` (Although you don't need to specify it explicitly as far as `emp_id` is PK, that could, probably, help avoid the confusion anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
create table prmr(
   emp_id number(10),
   name varchar2(10),
   mob number(10),
   id varchar2(10),
   email varchar2(20),
   CONSTRAINT PK_table PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
   CONSTRAINT unique_mob UNIQUE(mob)
);
```